# Display field from controller inside thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In my controller I have some calculations and at the end I have a `double balance` that returns me a desired output.

This is how its look:

```
@GetMapping("/userTransactions/{user_id}")
    public String getUserTransactions(@PathVariable("user_id") long user_id, TransactionGroup transactionGroup, Model model) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        long userId = user.getId();
        model.addAttribute("userId", userId);

        List<Transaction> transactions = transactionRepository.getTransactionsByUserId(user_id);
        List<TransactionGroup> transactionByDate = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Transaction> transOnSingleDate = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean currDates = transactions.stream().findFirst().isPresent();

        if (currDates) {
            LocalDate currDate = transactions.get(0).getDate();

            TransactionGroup transGroup = new TransactionGroup();

            for (Transaction t : transactions) {
                if (!currDate.isEqual(t.getDate())) {
                    transGroup.setDate(currDate);
                    transGroup.setTransactions(transOnSingleDate);
                    transactionByDate.add(transGroup);
                    transGroup = new TransactionGroup();
                    transOnSingleDate = new ArrayList<>();
                }

                transOnSingleDate.add(t);
                currDate = t.getDate();
            }
            transGroup.setDate(currDate);
            transGroup.setTransactions(transOnSingleDate);
            transactionByDate.add(transGroup);

            for (TransactionGroup group: transactionByDate) {
                LocalDate date = group.getDate();
                transactions = group.getTransactions();
                double income = transactions.stream()
                        .filter(trans -> trans.getTransactionType().getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase("income"))
                        .mapToDouble(Transaction::getAmount)
                        .sum();
                double expense = transactions.stream()
                        .filter(trans -> trans.getTransactionType().getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase("expense"))
                        .mapToDouble(Transaction::getAmount)
                        .sum();
                double balance = income - expense;
                model.addAttribute("balance", balance);
                System.out.println("date:" + date + ",income:" + income + ",expense:" + expense + ",balance:" + balance);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Empty");
        }


        model.addAttribute("transactionGroup", transactionByDate);
        return "transactions";
    }
```

You should see:

```
double balance = income - expense;
model.addAttribute("balance", balance);
```

And this is my thymeleaf:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/transaction.css}"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9ab80cc16b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Users</title>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1 class="logo">Spender</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" class="nav-toggle" id="nav-toggle">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a th:href="@{/api/test/homePage}">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a id="wallets" th:href="@{/api/wallet/userWallet/balance/{userId} (userId=${userId})}">Wallets</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: document.logoutForm.submit()" role="menuitem">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
        <span></span>
    </label>
</header>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="date" th:each="singleGroup  : ${transactionGroup}">
    <h1 th:text="${singleGroup .date}"></h1><h1 th:text="${balance}"></h1>
    <div class="transaction" th:each="singleTrans  : ${singleGroup.transactions}">
        <h2>Amount: <span th:text="${singleTrans.amount}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>Note: <span th:text="${singleTrans.note}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>Wallet name: <span th:text="${singleTrans .walletName}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>Expense Category: <span th:text="${singleTrans .expenseCategories}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>IncomeCategory: <span th:text="${singleTrans .incomeCategories}"></span></h2>
        <a class="card__link" th:href="@{/api/transaction/delete/{id}(id=${singleTrans.id})}"
           th:data-confirm-delete="|Are you sure you want to delete ${singleTrans.walletName} wallet?|"
           onclick="if (!confirm(this.getAttribute('data-confirm-delete'))) return false">Delete</a>
        <a class="card__link" th:href="@{/api/transaction/showFormForUpdate/{id}(id=${singleTrans.id})}">Update</a>
        <hr>

    </div>

</div>
<div style="text-align:center"
     th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(transactionGroup)}"><h1>You don't have any transaction</h1>
    <a th:href="@{/api/wallet/userWallet/balance/{userId} (userId=${userId})}">Wallets</a>
</div>


<form name="logoutForm" th:action="@{/api/auth/signout}" method="post" th:hidden="true">
    <input hidden type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to display that value right after

```
<h1 th:text="${singleGroup .date}"></h1>
```

And I tried like:

```
<h1 th:text="${singleGroup .date}"></h1><h1 th:text="${balance}"></h1>
```

What is the problem?

For example, my output in the console from the controller is good, and looks like this:

`date:2023-03-03,income:100.0,expense:50.0,balance:50.0`

`date:2023-03-16,income:100.0,expense:15.0,balance:85.0`

But on page, I have like in console, two dates and for both dates are printed `85` instead  `50` for date `03/03/2023` and `85` for  date `03/16/2023`, value `85` is printed for both of them.

How I can extract this double value in my thymeleaf to show appropiate value like in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your balance attribute is not part of transaction group. So, when you call `model.addAttribute("balance", balance);` in loop, your previous value is overwritten. Add balance attribute to transaction group instead